# Trying to set master layout view once and have it set for remainder of session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two separate master layout designs that I would like be able to use dynamically. Essentially, I'd like to use one if a user enters (logs in) the site via one URL, or a second if through a different URL.

Is there a way to set the "layout" view and maintain it as a user traverses the site? I'd prefer to handle it conditionally once and set something for that user's session. I don't want to handle it on every controller action.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Session` object from within the `_ViewStart.*html`. For example:

```
// cshtml
@{
    Layout = Session["Layout"];
}
```

```
' vbhtml
@Code
    Layout = Session("Layout")
End Code
```

How you set the session variable in the first place depends on your structure.

Comment: Ha, guess I should have read my own question for clues to the answer! This worked very well! I just do a quick session variable check on each of my _ViewStart pages now and set the Layout path accordingly. Thank you.